# Why is a local variable accessible in callback function only when it is a input parameter of the parent function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div id="header" p-include="components/header.htm" p-param="{'lblCurPos':'User Profile Page'}"></div>
<!--Other mark up here-->
<div id="footer" p-include="components/footer.htm" p-param="{'lblScreenID':'SYS-027'}"></div>
```

js Code:

```
/*Replace div that has p-include attr */
$(window).on('load',function() {
    $("div[p-include]").each(
        function () {
            p_include_replace(this);
            //p_include_replace2(this);
        }
    );   
});

//this works
function p_include_replace(obj) {
    //load html fragment
    $(obj).load($(obj).attr("p-include"), function(){
        //parse param
        param = JSON.parse($(obj).attr("p-param").replace(/'/g, '"'));        
        jQuery.each(param, function (k, val) {
            $("#" + k).html(val);
        });
    });
}

//this doesn't work
function p_include_replace2(obj) {
    //parse param    
    param = JSON.parse($(obj).attr("p-param").replace(/'/g, '"'));
    //load html fragment     
    $(obj).load($(obj).attr("p-include"), function(){        
        jQuery.each(param, function (k, val) {
            $("#" + k).html(val);
        });
    });
}
```

`p_include_replace2` would not work for the header because at the time of the `load` callback function executed, the local variable `param` is overwritten and contains the parameters for the footer.

But why is `p_include_replace` working? Why is it different to use `obj` / `param` in the callback function if both are local variables of the parent function?

20170413 Edit:

To clarify, I have change the code to the following:

```
/*Replace div that has p-include attr */
$(window).on('load',function() {
    $("div[p-include]").each(
        function () {            
            p_include_test(this);           
        }
    );   
});


function p_include_test(obj) {
    param = obj.id + "param"
    console.log("Parent:" + obj.id);
    console.log("Parent param:" + param);
    $(obj).load($(obj).attr("p-include"), function(){
       console.log("Callback:" + obj.id);
       console.log("Callback param:" + param);   
    });
}
```

And the result is the following:

[image: result]

Both `param` and `obj` have been changed outside of the callback, why can `obj` holds 2 different values in the callback correctly but not `param`?

Comment: Your latest added example shows your problem: You are using `param` without `var` which makes it a global variable. So you change it globally, which influences the other loops

Comment: @devnull69 I added `var` to my second method and it works! So `param` was actually a global variable; I get it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner function (load callback) in both cases is asynchronous. So in your first method, `param` changes only inside the callback, which is fine.

In your second method, you change param outside of the callback, without using `var`, so `param` is changed globally and is subject to further change before the callback is even called once. This change also changes `param` inside of the callback, so the outcome is not deterministic.

Comment: But how dose it work for `obj`? Why can it holds 2 different values but `param` can only hold 1?

Comment: I don't get you ... where does `obj` change inside your methods?

Comment: The first method was called twice before the callback is even called once. Once for the header and once for the footer. Why is `obj` holding the correct value each time in the callback function executed afterward? I don't understand how it is different from `param`

Comment: Because (1) obj is not changed only its content. It's still the same object (2) the content of obj is only changed INSIDE the callback, which is equivalent to `param` only being changed inside of it.

Comment: but the content of obj has also changed out of the callback? I have edited the question to add clarification

Answer (score -1):

Once you replace a div (or other element) you've removed something from the DOM and added it back again. Therefore you need to use delegation. You can't listen for something that wasn't originally part of the DOM unless you look for a parent element that was already there. This problem has bit me more than once.

[Check this out](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: The question doesn't have anything to do with event binding